# Did the alleged victim of Julian Assange's Swedish sex crime say that police made it up?

Tags: sexual-abuse, law-enforcement, julian-assange

In [this interview with John Pilger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sbT3_9dJY4&feature=youtu.be&t=23m25s), Julian Assange says

> ...here we have case where... the woman herself says the police made it up.
>
> ... But what is the rhetoric? The rhetoric is... never mentioned that the woman herself says the police made it up.

Is it true that woman in question says the police made the charge up? What evidence for this is there?

Answer (score 8):

Assange is accused of raping one woman (SW) and molesting another (AA). He previously had consensual sex with both of them. The accusation is that he then had unprotected sex with both of them against their will and while one of them was asleep.

From the [police interview](http://www.nnn.se/nordic/assange/docs/protocol.pdf), regarding SW:

> [SW] squeezed her legs together because she did not want to have intercourse with him without protection
>   [...]
>   They dozed off and she awoke and felt him penetrating her. She immediately asked, “Are you wearing anything?”, to which he replied, “You”.

Regarding AA:

> According to Anna, “everything went so fast”. He tore off her clothes and in the process pulled at and broke her necklace. Anna tried to put some clothes back on, because it all went so fast and she felt uncomfortable; but Assange immediately took them off again. Anna states that in fact she felt that she no longer wanted to go any further
>   [...]
>   Anna sensed that Assange wanted to insert his penis in her vagina right away, which she did not want because he was not wearing a condom. She therefore tried to twist her hips to the side and squeeze her legs together in order to prevent penetration. Anna tried several times to reach for a condom, but Assange stopped her from doing so by holding her arms and prying open her legs while trying to penetrate her with his penis without a condom. Anna says that eventually she was on the verge of tears because she was held fast and could not get a condom, and felt that ‘this can end badly’.
>   [...]
>   Anna and Assange resumed having sex and Anna says that she thought that she “just wanted to get it over with”.
>   [...]
>   Anna is convinced that when he withdrew from her the first time, Assange deliberately broke the condom at its tip and then continued copulating to ejaculation.

The claim that the woman says that the police made the charges up originates from this [Affidavit by Julian Assange](https://wikileaks.org/IMG/html/Affidavit_of_Julian_Assange.html#efmNdPOCv):

> While the younger woman was at the police station on 20 August 2010,
>   her phone records show that she wrote that she:
>
> > did not want to put any charges on JA but that the police were keen on getting a grip on him (sv: få tag på honom) (14:26);110
>
> and that
>
> > she was “chocked [sic: shocked] when they arrested JA because she only wanted him to take a test (17:06)”.111

The footnote says:

> My lawyers have been refused a copy of the phone records in full; the citation is paraphrased and is a direct quote from my lawyers' email.

As the phone records are not part of a public record, there is no proof one way or another about their existence. It may or may not be true that the women did not want to press any charges.

The police interviews are not made up, but approved by SW and AA. Based on their description in the interview, the police can press charges for rape.

Comment: Then I guess OP’s question is: is the affidavit stating the truth? Is this version of the events contested?